# Load more images on scroll or on button click (without mysql)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, scroll, infinity

i have this php code who auto thumb and arrange my photos to gallery:

```
<?php
$folder = "../albums/1000/";
$folder3 = "albums/1000/";
$handle = opendir($folder);
$noeffect = "noeffect";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
                if (strpos($file, '.png',1)||strpos($file, '.jpg',1)||strpos($file, '.JPG',1) ) { 
$imgsrc= "../thumbnail.php?file=";
$imgend= "&width=120&height=120";
    echo ("
    <li><a href=\"".$folder.$file."\" rel=\"".$rel.external."\" class=\"".$noeffect."\">
 <img src=\"".$imgsrc.$folder3.$file.$imgend."\" /></a></li> "); }}
?>
```

it works great and i love it! but when i upload 200-300 pictures it need to load the thumbs before it could view the big picture in the gallery.. 
i search the net and tried many things but most of them use mysql and i dont know how to deal it and others were problematic.. any solution? thanks!

You can take a look here for example for what im doing : http://m.eladhamemagnet.net/albums/996.php

btw its for iphone so thats why i need it to load fast

Comment: What is the problem?  You simply want to ensure thumbs are loaded before anything else?  Why would you want to do this?  Let the browser worry about it for you.

Comment: the problem was that you couldn't see any photo until the whole page was fully loaded.. i figure how to fix it thanks..

Comment: then you need to post your answer here.  How can others with your same problem find the answer if you don't post an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. i did preload for any photo.. so when the thumbnail is loaded also the big picture..

```
<?
$folder = "../albums/996/";
$folder3 = "albums/996/";
$handle = opendir($folder);
$noeffect = "noeffect";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
                if (strpos($file, '.png',1)||strpos($file, '.jpg',1)||strpos($file, '.JPG',1) ) { 
$folder2 = ""; 
$imgsrc= "../thumbnail.php?file=";
$imgend= "&width=120&height=120";
    echo ("
    <li><a href=\"".$folder.$file."\" rel=\"".$rel.external."\" class=\"".$noeffect."\">
 <img src=\"".$imgsrc.$folder3.$file.$imgend."\" />
</a></li>

");
$pre = "../";
$jss = "text/javascript";
echo (" <script  type=\"".$jss."\">
if (document.images) {
    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src =\"".$folder.$file."\";
}
</script>");
  }
}
?>
```